# Android Studio picasso class not found exception

Tags: picasso

I have migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

In Eclipse, my project is running perfectly after migrating to Android Studio app is crashing.

I have check the log cat it shows picasso not class found exception but I have included lib file picasso 2.5.2 from library dependency & dependency declare in gradle file like below:

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

My gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Please let me know why app get crashed?

Comment: posting your full build.gradle and stacktrace will help

Comment: When am tried for post total gradle but stacktrace showing some errors. so unable to post total gradle

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/posting-a-stack-trace to check posting stacktrace... try posting stacktrace

Comment: If I'm not too late, do you still have the picasso jar file in your lib folder?